# (Android) How to disable all Buttons/CheckBoxes/Other Widgets inside a ScrollView but not disable the scrolling

Tags: java, android, widget, scrollview

I have an Activity that contains a ScrollView. This ScrollView contains a TableLayout many Widgets inside of it. When the user clicks a Button, I would like to disable all of the Widgets inside the TableLayout, but not disable the scrolling. The user needs to be able to look at what is inside of the ScrollView but simply not interact with it. I have searched around the internet and haven't been able to find an answer that works for me. If you have any solutions, please post them here. Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Use `your_widget.setEnabled(false);` to change the state enabled to disabled, true otherwise. You must set it for each widget you want disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially started out with Yaw Asare's answer and found that it didn't work in my situation. Prior to running into this bug in my application, I had set up the Player 1 and Player 2 Widgets and their onClick methods. What I had to do to fix my bug was to reimplement these functions and set their onClick methods to do nothing and then recalling the initial methods when I needed these enabled once more. I did not actually disable the clicking of these Widgets but changed their onClick methods. Thanks very much to all that responded to this question. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

A ScrollView extends ViewGroup, so you can use the getChildCount() and getChildAt(index) methods to iterate through your children.
So, it would look something like this:

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.yourscrollid);
for ( int i = 0; i < scroll.getChildCount();  i++ ){
    View view = scroll.getChildAt(i);
    view.setEnabled(false); // Or whatever you want to do with the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call `setEnabled(false)` on each view in the `ScrollView`. To make this easier you could add all views you want disabled to a `ViewGroup` and then when you want to enable/disable the sub views just iterate through the Views in the `ViewGroup`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the frame layout for it.Try the below code

xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" >
        </TableLayout>
        <!-- below frame layout is to disable the whole view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now in your activity inside the onCreate() method write the below code.

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        fl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This will disable the click on the every child of your view.